# PowerShell: How to get cmd comp to run quietly?

Tags: powershell, cmd, file-comparison

I want to test the results of both the `cmd` commands `comp` and `FC` running in PowerShell on a series of files. I have succeeded in getting `FC` to run quietly in a script and yield correct results. In a `cmd` batch file, `comp` can run quietly by prefixing it with `echo N |`, but that is not working in PowerShell.

Here is a test script:

```
$LastExitCode = 99
$sItem_1 = "C:\temp\file 1.txt"
$sItem_2 = "C:\temp\file 2.txt"
write-output "Do FC:"
cmd.exe /c "FC /b ""$sItem_1"" ""$sItem_2"" > null"
write-output $LastExitCode
$LastExitCode = 99
write-output "Do comp:"
cmd.exe /c "echo N | comp ""$sItem_1"" ""$sItem_2"" > null"
write-output $LastExitCode
```

and here is the console output of that script:

```
PS> test 2.ps1
Do FC:
0
Do comp:
cmd.exe : Compare more files (Y/N) ? 
At test 2.ps1:9 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c "echo N | comp ""$sItem_1"" ""$sItem_2"" > null"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Compare more files (Y/N) ? :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS>
```

In the second line of output, the zero exit code means that `FC` found the files to be identical. But when PowerShell attempted to run `comp`, it choked on the "Compare more" prompt.

How can I get this to run?

Comment: Just to be clear, neither `comp` or `fc` are "`cmd` commands"! They are both independent commandline executable files.

Comment: A bit beside the point, but doesn't `> null` redirect the output to a file called `null` instead of really suppressing it? Whereas `> nul` without double-l does not create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `comp.exe`'s `/M` option to suppress the prompt for further comparisons.

  - Run `comp /?` to see all options.
  - Curiously, as of this writing the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp) do *not* mention `/M`.
- There is no need to call `comp.exe` or `fc.exe` *via `cmd /c`* from PowerShell. Given that they're *external programs* (executables), you can invoke them directly.

  - Use `>$null` to silence stdout output, `2>$null` to silence stderr; `*>$null` silences both streams.
  - In direct invocation of external programs, PowerShell never requires you to enclose variable values in `"..."`

Therefore:

```
$sItem_1 = "C:\temp\file 1.txt"
$sItem_2 = "C:\temp\file 2.txt"

"Do FC:"
fc /b$ sItem_1 $sItem_2 >$null
$LastExitCode

$LastExitCode = 99
"Do comp:"
comp /M $sItem_1 $sItem_2 >$null
$LastExitCode
```

Comment: Is that `/m` switch new? A pretty obvious solution, I should have known about that! Thank you for it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @NewSites. My _guess_ is that the switch has been around for a while; `comp /?` shows it.

Comment: I just checked the official documentation, and it does not include the `/m` switch, even though it's dated in Feb. of this year: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp

Comment: @NewSites, that's unfortunate; I've seen similar omissions in the past (and I don't think they are necessarily indicative of an option having been recently introduced). At the bottom of the page there is an option to create a GitHub issue to report a problem with the page, which I encourage you to do.